# can <too> (meaning also) come before the end of sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, also-too

I want to say:

> This challenge too gets resolved soon.

meaning this challenge also gets resolved. is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically correct.  You can replace "too" with "also", if you wish, but there's no need for you to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  You might do this for emphasis, sentence variety, or to eliminate ambiguity.  To illustrate ambiguity, consider the following sentences:

```
I, too, would like to visit Italy.
I would like to visit Italy, too.
```

In the former sentence it's clear that you want to visit Italy in addition to others who want to visit Italy.  In the latter, it might mean the same as the former, or it might mean that you want to visit Italy as well as other countries.  Only context can determine the meaning in the second example.

Comment: +1 for a good example!

Comment: For even more fun you could say *I would too like to visit Italy* but there the meaning is different entirely.  It expresses disagreement with the assertion that I wouldn’t like to visit Italy, synonymous with *in deed*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can say, for example, "I, too, enjoy eating".

It would sound better to say, "This challenge will get resolved soon, too" or "This challenge will get resolved soon, as well".

Comment: Actually, it sounds better to say "this challenge too", as this avoids running the two adverbs together, which sounds slightly clunky [sic].